# antlr 4 - warning: rule contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I work with antlr v4 to write a t-sql parser.
Is this warning a problem?

> "rule 'sqlCommit' contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string"

My Code:

```
sqlCommit: COMMIT (TRAN | TRANSACTION | WORK)? id?;

id:
ID  | CREATE | PROC | AS | EXEC | OUTPUT| INTTYPE |VARCHARTYPE |NUMERICTYPE |CHARTYPE |DECIMALTYPE | DOUBLETYPE | REALTYPE
|FLOATTYPE|TINYINTTYPE|SMALLINTTYPE|DATETYPE|DATETIMETYPE|TIMETYPE|TIMESTAMPTYPE|BIGINTTYPE|UNSIGNEDBIGINTTYPE..........
;

ID: (LETTER | UNDERSCORE | RAUTE) (LETTER | [0-9]| DOT | UNDERSCORE)*
```

In a version before I used directly the lexer rule ID instead of the parser rule id in sqlCommit. But after change ID to id the warning appears.

(**Hint** if you are confused of ID and id: I want to use the parser rule id instead of ID because an identifier can be a literal which maybe already matched by an other lexer rule)

Regards

**EDIT**
With the help of "280Z28" I solved the problem. In the parser rule "id" was one slash more than needed:
    BITTYPE|CREATE|PROC|
    |AS|EXEC|OUTPUT|

So the | | includes that the parser rule can match an empty string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a Google search:

[`ErrorType.EPSILON_OPTIONAL`](http://www.antlr.org/api/JavaTool/org/antlr/v4/tool/ErrorType.html#EPSILON_OPTIONAL)

> Compiler Warning 154.
>
> rule *rule* contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
>
> A rule contains an optional block (`(...)?`) around an empty alternative.
>
> The following rule produces this warning.
>
> ```
> x  : ;
> y  : x?;                                // warning 154
> z1 : ('foo' | 'bar'? 'bar2'?)?;         // warning 154
> z2 : ('foo' | 'bar' 'bar2'? | 'bar2')?; // ok
> ```
>
> Since:
>   4.1

The problem described by this warning is primarily a performance problem. By wrapping a zero-length string in an optional block, you added a completely unnecessary decision to the grammar (whether to enter the optional block or not) which has a high likelihood of forcing the prediction algorithm through its slowest path. It's similar to wrapping Java code in the following:

```
if (slowMethodThatAlwaysReturnsTrue()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hello 280Z28, I had google the problem before I post my question here. But it seems I had google too little - sorry for that. Thank you very much for your help, I found the mistake and will edit my question.

Comment: @SamHarwell As I understand, warning 154 mandates that no alternative should match empty string. But why the first rule `x : ;` doesn't trigger warning 154? The rule `x` is simply blank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to see how this rule also suffers from this warning (with antlr 4.7.1)

```
join_type: (INNER | (left_right_full__join_type)? (OUTER)?)? JOIN;

left_right_full__join_type: LEFT | RIGHT | FULL;

JOIN:        J O I N;
INNER:       I N N E R;
OUTER:       O U T E R;
```

AFAICT it *always* returns **JOIN** and optionally preceded by the type.